# Fetching data in redux-reduver

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have the following reducer-function where I want to fetch data and update the requestedData state. Somehow I can't return the variable tempData. Do you know why this doesn't work and how it could work?

Thanks in advance!

```
const initialState={
        requestedData: []
    };
    
    const reducers = (state=initialState,action)=> {
        switch (action.type) {
            case 'UPDATE_REQUESTED_DATA':
                var tempData;
                fetch('https://someapp.herokuapp.com/restaurants')
                        .then((response) => response.json())
                        .then((json)=> {
                            tempData = { ...state,
                                requestedData: json
                            }
                        });
                return tempData;
    
            default:
                return state;
        }
    };
    
    
    export default reducers;
```

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to use packages like `Redux Thunk` for creating `Side Effects` such as Calling `external apis`.

Second, use `Redux Thunk`: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk

Third, use `Redux Thunk`: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk

Fourth if you need to some how stick to your current code you need to try something like this:

```
const initialState = {
  requestedData: [],
};

const reducers = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "UPDATE_REQUESTED_DATA":
      var tempData;
      return fetch("https://someapp.herokuapp.com/restaurants")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((json) => {
          tempData = { ...state, requestedData: json };
          return tempData;
        });

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default reducers;
```